# iOS: How to detect FinishedLaunching after app's memory got cleared by OS

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to detect when an iOS app that was already open, then moved to the background, is re-opened after the phone cleared its memory. The app basically resets and WillEnterForeground doesn't get called. Does anyone know if there's a way to handle an app brought to the foreground after the phone cleared its memory?

PS: I'm using Xamarin/C# but I don't mind suggestions in Swift, I'll adapt it to my environment

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to have 'didRecieveMemoryWarning' act appropriately before the app actually shuts down from running out of memory, then when you reopen you can restore your state.  Not 100% sure on this

Comment: ReceiveMemoryWarning gets called from the appdelegate when I simulate it (using the simulator), but is it always called before memory actually gets cleared? It doesn't when I force it (power button held, then home button for a few seconds to clear the memory), but I'm not sure if forcing it duplicates the actual process when memory gets freed up in favor of apps in the foreground

Answer (score 0):

When the system restarts your application in the background it's for a reason: maybe you're receiving location updates or maybe you're getting a notification that a background file transfer was complete, a push notification, etc.

You will receive a call in the AppDelegate method that's used to handle that, for example `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` for the case of a notification.

If your app runs out of memory while in the foreground the system will kill it, but not restart it (in the foreground).

Comment: iOS may free up memory to the benefit of the application in the foreground even when the apps in the background aren't doing anything (no location updates, no file transfer), it's just because it favors the application being used. You can simulate that behavior by opening an app of your choice, let's say a game for instance, kill all the other apps. Now press the home button to move the app to the background, hold the power button until you see the swipe to turn off screen, then hold the home button until it closes that "turn off" screen. Go back to your game and you'll see it restart.